# Cannot delete Content Builder Asset using SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, content-assets

I am trying to delete asset using SSJS (CloudPage) so that we can automate the deletion of unused assets from Content Builder. I could not find SFMC documentation for DELETE method but could see that Greg was able to use these methods:https://gortonington.com/restapimethodinssjs/

When I try DELETE method, I get error: **Error Message: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object**

Code:

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1");
try{
  var url = "https://mc11111.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v2/token";
    var contentType = "application/json";
    var payload =
        '{"grant_type": "client_credentials","client_id": "aaaaaaa","client_secret": "bbbbbb","account_id":"111111"}';

    var accessTokenResult = HTTP.Post(url, contentType, payload);
    var accResult = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(accessTokenResult["Response"][0]);
    var accessToken= accResult.access_token;
    
    if (accessToken != "") {
      
  var url2 = "https://mc11111.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/asset/v1/content/assets/123456?isCdnDelete=1";
  var headerValues = ["Bearer " + accessToken];
      var content1 = [0];
  var req = new Script.Util.HttpRequest(url2);
  req.emptyContentHandling = 0;
  req.retries = 2;
  req.continueOnError = true;
  req.contentType = "application/json"
  req.setHeader = ("Authorization", headerValues);
  req.method = "DELETE"; /*** You can change the method here ***/
  req.postData = content1;

  var resp = req.send();
    }
 }
 catch (err) {
  Write("Error Message: " + Stringify(err.message) + Stringify(err.description));
 }
</script>
```

Comment: I'd suggest getting it working in Postman first.

Comment: Hi Adam, it works through Postman but not able to perform it through CloudPage or Script activity